# iPhone. Change status bar color in IB doesn't work

Tags: iphone, statusbar, uistatusbar

I know, it sounds pretty stupid, but changing status bar color in IB, doesn't change anything.
It always stays gray. I can change in code to black(works), but still I have this gray bar during first start.
XCode is 4.2 beta, can't download new one now.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the style of status bar in your Info.plist file. So that it is displayed correctly at the start.

Use "Status bar style" as key or "UIStatusBarStyle" if you are using raw values. Then set it to the desired style.